# Why this code is giving segmentation fault in linked list intersection?

Tags: linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int val)
    {
        data=val;
        next=NULL;
    }
};

Node* findIntersection(Node* head1, Node* head2)
{
    // Your Code Here
    Node* h=nullptr;
    Node* temp=h;
    while(head2!=nullptr){
        while(head1!=nullptr && head1->data<head2->data){
            
            head1=head1->next;
        }
        cout<<head1->data<<endl;
        if(head1->data==head2->data){
            if(h==nullptr){
                h=new Node(head1->data);
            }
            else{
                temp->next=new Node(head1->data);
                     temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
        head2=head2->next;
       
    }
    return h;
}
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    Node* l1= new Node(1);
    l1->next=new Node(2);
    l1->next->next=new Node(3);
    l1->next->next->next=new Node(4);
    l1->next->next->next->next=new Node(6);
    
    Node* l2=new Node(2);
    l1->next=new Node(4);
    l1->next->next=new Node(6);
    l1->next->next->next=new Node(8);
    findIntersection(l1,l2);
    

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to find intersection of two linked lists with elements in sorted order.
This is a question on GFG which can be found on link:
[https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/intersection-of-two-sorted-linked-lists/1?page=1&category[]=Linked%20List&sortBy=difficulty](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/intersection-of-two-sorted-linked-lists/1?page=1&category%5B%5D=Linked%20List&sortBy=difficulty)

Answer (score 0):

> Why this code is giving segmentation fault in linked list intersection?

Because there are bugs in it. You'll benefit from learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

> `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`

Unrelated to your crash, but you should *never* `#include` anything from the `bits` directory.

```
 while(head2!=nullptr){
        while(head1!=nullptr && head1->data<head2->data){   
            head1=head1->next;
        }
        // We could get here if head1==nullptr. The next line will crash.
        cout<<head1->data<<endl;
...
            else {
                // temp was assigned NULL in the start, and now is being dereferenced.
                temp->next=new Node(head1->data);
                temp=temp->next;
            }
```